# Database type missing from database.yml, but the database is already setup, if I add it to the yml will it reset the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, config

I am jumping into an existing project, and the local database.yml file does not include staging. I was transferring some files with capistrano linked files, and it pushed up the databasel.yml by default.

Now when deploying to staging I get the error 
`ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'staging' database is not configured. Available: ["default", "development", "test", "production"]`

I have no idea to find out the password to the staging database since no previous developers are here. They must have edited this file directly on staging, since I don't see it in the git history, and my 5 past releases don't seem to include it either (I must have pushed things up since it was overwritten).

If I add a staging db to the database.yml will it override the data that is there now? It is staging so it is not the biggest deal in the world, but it would be a big pain and I want to try to fix this issue without overriding the data.

I am using Postgres.

Any tips on how I can get this back in order would be super appreciative.

Comment: Adding the database to `-staging` would not reset the database. It will only connect to it. Resetting it would require you to run the appropriate rake commands or manually deleting and recreating the database from the db client

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming if this staging env is previously used, it must have the database creds on database.yml for the active record to save/retrieve data accordingly. You can try logging in as root in your staging sql and you can reset password for your staging database(assuming you have root creds).

If not, and you can't possibly get the database info, I believe you can point your staging to a new database if loss of data is tolerable.

Comment: Thanks for responding, yes it was prev used and I would want to avoid data loss just to save time in having to recreate it. I have root access, how can I reset my password through ssh?

Comment: you can login to your mysql console as root, list all databases, find the staging one(in your case, guess the staging one) and update that database name to database.yml under staging and check if it has enough backup data, that way you can know if its the correct database. This way, even if you point to the wrong one, the right one will still be there and there won't be any loss of data.